# Any chance to use holoeverywhere and appcompat together?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-holo-everywhere, android-appcompat

Since google released the new support library v7, I use the appcompat library instead of actionbarsherlock. With the appcompat library the actionbar still works, if I disable the recreating at orientation change (android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"), which saves me a lot of work. But for the user experiece of android >=2.1 and <3.0 users, i would be happy, if I could continue to use holoeverywhere (which depends on ABS).

I've tried to setup ABS as library for holoeverywhere and then AppCompat and holoeverywhere as libraries for my App, but it doesn't work.

I'd appreciate your help.

EDIT:
I haven't found any solution to get them work together. But I found out, that I can use the Holo Style Generator ([link](http://android-holo-colors.com/)) to change the drawables of most UI components (e.g. EditText etc.). After the theme is generated, you only have to change the parent style in the files from:

```
res/values/themes_apptheme:     <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black"> 
res/values-v11/themes_apptheme: <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a little late now, but newer versions of HoloEverywhere come with AppCompat instead of ABS.

Personally I tend to struggle with this, as porting ABS projects to AppCompat turned out to be a pain, but there are definitely advantages of using the 'official' solution in the long run.